# LAMMPS build error C1090: PDB API call failed, error code '5'

Tags: c++, cmake, build-error, lammps

I'm trying to build my LAMMPS library after adding to a simple int return test function to see if I could access the library's files through C# & Unity.

I'm using cmake to compile, with the following command:

```
 cmake ../cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=yes -DBUILD_MPI=no
```

I then try to build with this command:

```
cmake --build . --clean-first
```

Keep in mind, these exact commands have worked in the past, and I have been able to obtain the .dll I need and access it in Unity. However, for some reason I have started getting this error in the build stage:

```
lammps\src\body.cpp : fatal error C1090: PDB API call failed, error code '5': 
lammps\build\lammps.dir\Debug\vc143.pdb [lammps\build\lammps.vcxproj]
```

The file it gets stuck on changes. The build before that, it stopped on atom_vec_tri.cpp, and the build before that was atom_vec_sphere.cpp.
I tried to search for this specific error code, but have found nothing. The other forum posts I have found are talking about Dropbox background processes, which my computer does not have. Is there something else going on? I'm not really sure why it's so inconsistent and why it has just started happening again.

EDIT: Without me changing anything at all (arrowing back up in the console to the same commands I had typed out earlier just to try one more time) it worked. I don't know what the difference is, and it would still be great if anybody has any idea of how to fix this in the future!

EDIT EDIT: Well, that last time when it 'worked' it didn't fully make the shared library (dll.recipe & not dll). Now, it's back to the error. Really not sure what's going on here.